# When can we compute Westfall and Young's $p$-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

[Westfall and Young](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2532216) provide a method for adjusting $p$-values following multiple hypothesis tests. I have two questions about when this method can be applied:

1. Can the corrected $p$-values be computed when the (uncorrected) $p$-values have themselves been computed using bootstrapped standard errors? I would assume that this is, at the very least, very computationally expensive.
2. Can the corrected $p$-values be computed in situation where I estimate just *one* regression model but want to test a series of hypotheses relating to several different explanatory variables? (For example, imagine that I estimate the regression $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + u$ and want to test the two hypotheses that $\beta_1 = 0$ and $\beta_2 = 0$.) I would assume that the answer to this second question is 'yes'. However, I ask because, as far as I can see, the only implementation in Stata (*wyoung*) does not compute $p$-values in such cases.